# Upper bound of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

I have the sequence a non-negative sequence $u_k$ that satisfy the following relation
$$ u_{k+1} \leq u_k + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^d (\Delta_{i,k+1})^2$$
where $\alpha > 0$, $d \in \mathbb{N}$ (fixed) and $\Delta_{i,k+1}$ is a non-increasing non-negative sequence with $\underset{k \rightarrow \infty} {\lim} \Delta_{i,k+1}= 0, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm looking to find an upper bound for $u_k$. From the above, I can write
$$ u_{k+1} \leq u_0 + \alpha \sum_{i=1}^d \left((\Delta_{i,k+1})^2 + \dots + (\Delta_{i,1})^2 \right)$$
If I impose that $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\Delta_{i,k+1})^2 < \infty, \forall 1 \leq i \leq d$, then I could say that $u_k$ can be upper bounded by a certain constant $C$. Is there a way to prove things without this assumption or at least relax it?

Thanks.

Comment: @Dude: I've updated the description where $d$ is actually fixed. So you are saying that each term $\Delta_{i,k}$ is bounded because of the limit assumption? can you elaborate more?

Comment: I was wrong in the last comment. I would say that you cannot conclude that $u_k$ is bounded. But from you last inequality, you can say that if each $\Delta{i, k}$ is asymptotic to $1/k^{a}$ with $a>1/2$, then your sequence is bounded.

Comment: Which is just an example, in fact your imposed condition is more general.

Comment: @Dude: thanks for your clarification.